# how to change UI of checkout page on woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have try to change UI of checkout page on `woocommerce`. I have try set checkout page same as a  below link: http://demo.smartaddons.com/templates/joomla3/sj-tini/index.php/checkout

please suggest any idea regarding this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In wordpress, you can change the UI of the checkout page.Although you can change all the pages.Follow some steps :
1:Create a folder with name "woocommerce" in active theme.
2: Copy the checkout folder in theme.
Here is the syntax:

```
Plugin checkout folder : wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout.

Theme checkout folder  : wp-content/themes/woocommerce/checkout.
```

Now when you copy the plugin checkout folder to the theme as per discussion above.Then your UI of the checkout page will be linked
to the theme checkout folder and you can easily change it.
 
For any dought,please email me.
Note:Difference of the folder structure is "templates" folder.

Answer (score 0):

There are a set of several templates that control the checkout page. They can be found in the WooCommerce plugin folder in `templates/checkout`.

You can put a `woocommerce/templates/checkout` folder inside your theme's folder and copy the templates you want to alter into it.

Those will override the normal templates without altering the plugin itself. That way your changes won't get overwritten when WooCommerce is updated.

Hope it helps you.